# Jquery Ajax REST Nested lists and people pickers

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest, sharepoint-online, jscript

Using Ajax/Rest/Jquery/Sharepoint lists...
List:Users -> Department -> Manager
 (Manager is a People-Picker item in Departments, which is treated like a 3rd list).
This gets me to the second tier. I can use row[Department].Title to access "Title" for instance from the lookup field Department, or any other field in there that's not a lookup to another list.
This is where it gets hairy...
Manager is a People-picker field in the Department list.
What I need is to be able to grab the manager's name, which is a layer further.
Using the query above as a baseline in theory (not reality) it would look like:

```
&$select=Username/Name,Department/Name,Department/Manager/Name&$expand=Username,Department,Department/Manager
```

I have tried different methods to pull this data. The end result that I'm looking for is to have one row with columns User, Title, Department, Manager ...

Here is what I have currently:

```
url: siteURL + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('USERLISTNAME')/Items?$select=ID,Employee/Title,Employee/EMail,Title,Office_x0020_Phone,Remote_x0020_Phone,Department/Title&$expand=Department,Employee";

...

function Success__Handler(data) {
    try {
        var DataTable = $('#EMPLOYEE').DataTable();
        if (DataTable != 'undefined') {
            DataTable.destroy();
        }
        DataTable = $('#EMPLOYEE').DataTable({
            "aaData": data.d.results,
            order: [[0,'asc']],
            "aoColumns": [{
                "mData": "Employee.Title",
            }, {
                "mData": "Department.Title",
                "render": function(data, type, row, meta){

            }, {
                "mData": "Employee.Title",
            }, {
                "mData": "Department.Title",
                "render": function(data, type, row, meta){
                    if (row['Department']['results'].length == 0) {
                        return "";
                    } else { 
                        for ( i=0, l=row['Department']['results'].length; i<l; i++) {
                            if ( i == 0 ) {
                                departments= row['Department']['results'][i].Title;
                            } else {
                                departments = departments + '<br/>' + row['Department']['results'][i].Title;
                            }
                        }
                        return brands;
                    }
                }
...
```

Department/Manager doesn't work I get an invalid field error. I believe my issue resides in the initial query. I've seen different posts about nested queries, but none seem to work. I looked at the REST API documentation and it mentions nested lists, but I can't get any of their examples to translate into this situation.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The way I got around this was the nest the user initialization inside the success handler for the departments initialization. Not the best approach, I know there's probably an easier solution, but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

*Nested* OData expands are not supported in SharePoint.

Given the example

```
Employees (primary list, which contains Department lookup field 
   |
   ->  Departments (foreign list, which contains Manager user field)
```

you could consider the following solution.

1) split into two requests:

- `/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Employee')/items?$select=Title,DepartmentId` return employee list along with `department id`
- `/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Department')/items?$select=Id,Title,Manager/Title&$expand=Manager`  retrieve department list along with manager details

2)combine the results on the client side. Since SharePoint Online supports [batch requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/make-batch-requests-with-the-rest-apis), both requests could be performed a single request (e.g. via [datajs](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=datajs) library as demonstrated below)

**Example**

```
var jsonSPHeaders = {  
    "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose", 
    "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    "DataServiceVersion": "3.0" 
};

OData.request( {
    requestUri: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/$batch",
    method: "POST",
    headers: { "X-RequestDigest": document.getElementById("__REQUESTDIGEST").value,
               "DataServiceVersion": "3.0" },
    data: { __batchRequests: [
       { requestUri: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Employee')/items?$select=Title,DepartmentId", method: "GET" , headers: jsonSPHeaders },
       { requestUri: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Department')/items?$select=Id,Title,Manager/Title&$expand=Manager", method: "GET" , headers: jsonSPHeaders },
    ]}
},
function (data, response) {
     var result = data.__batchResponses[0].data.results.map(function(item){
         var projectedItem = resolveProjectedItem(data.__batchResponses[1].data.results,item.DepartmentId) || {};
         projectedItem.Manager = projectedItem.Manager || {};
         return {
             "employee" : item.Title,
             "department": projectedItem.Title,
             "manager": projectedItem.Manager.Title
         };
     });
     console.log(result);
}, 
null, 
OData.batchHandler);
```

where

```
function resolveProjectedItem(items,id){
   var result = items.filter(function(item){
        if(item.Id === id)
           return item;
   });
   if(result.length > 0)
      return result[0];
   return null   
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The way I got around this was the nest the user initialization inside the success handler for the departments initialization. Not the best approach, I know there's probably an easier solution, but it worked.

Comment: It answered my question, but in a round-about fashion. I had to iterate the department list first, then set an array with the manager's departments. Then re-iterate that array in the success handler of the user datatable and compare it against the department field. As I said, I'd like a better solution, but this is the only way I've found to do it so far.
I would choose it as an answer if I could until someone came up with a better way. Apparently you cannot answer your own questions. :)